# Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '0' In Hive : Operator With Left Join in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hive-query

I am joining 2 tables and using <= in Join Condition also applying one filter condition so that it can only fetch remaining data from left table where filter condition is true.

I am using below query.

```
SELECT * FROM  test.TABLE1 T1 
left join test.TABLE2 T2 
on (
T1.low<=T2.low
) 
where  t1.ID='1';
```

Error:

```
 Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 
[Error 10017]: Line 4:0 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '0' (state=42000,code=10017)
```

When I am only giving '=' condition instead of <= then its running without any issue.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a valid qry. Same query works in my hive. What is your version also is it possible to share your table structure. My test SQL `select * from t2p t1
left join tmp2 on (tmp2.b <= t1.id)
WHERE t1.name ='dum'`

Comment: Apache Hive (version 1.2.1000.2.6.3.0-235)

@KoushikRoy For me still is showing same error.

Comment: the  old version is causing this issue i think. So, workaround is, what is your SQL supposed to do? can you do something like this - `select * from (SELECT t1.*,t2.low as t2low FROM  test.TABLE1 T1 
join (select MAX(low) low from test.TABLE2) T2 ) rs
where  t1.ID='1' and t2low <=t1.low`. notice i used a subqry and max to join.

Comment: For your example, using my query, i can see it should work. See, max of table2.low is 12. Anything less than equal to 12 should come from table 1. And then filter id=1 should further exclude unwanted ones. What is your output for my qry for your scenario in your question.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Accoring to left Join all the matching records from right table and remaining records from left table should be available so Ideally if we are using left join then 14 from left table also should be available but its not showing in output.

Comment: Can you try, `select * from (SELECT t1.*,t2.low as t2low FROM  test.TABLE1 T1  left join (select MAX(low) low from test.TABLE2) T2 ) rs where  t1.ID='1' and t2low >=t1.low`.

Comment: @KoushikRoy tried It's same. since we are writing join condition in where clause, so every-time it will give result based on where filter and will not consider remaining records of left table.WHERE clause is applied after the JOIN is made. Thats by I want to write this condition in On clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
with data as ( Select * FROM test.TABLE1 t1 WHERE t1.ID='1')
Select * 
FROM data T1
LEFT JOIN test.TABLE2 T2 on T1.low<=T2.low
```

Comment: will this work like left Join. I guess It's a inner Join b/w table. I need to take table1 as left table.

Comment: @Sonu i edited my answer, try now.

Comment: same error.@ Bartosz Olchowik